# "Change DB Prefix" wordpress plugin error/issue: redirecting all HTTP traffic to /wp-admin/install.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I installed 'change db prefix' wordpress plugin (WordPress version being used is 3.7.1), which resulted in an error and has blocked all kind of http access to the site (domain as well as /wp-admin pages).

Got the following errors while installation -
Changing value: mdv_user_roles in table mdv_options: Failed
Changing values in table mdv_usermeta: Failed

This is what is happening now -
Whether I try to log into my /wp-admin or just access domain directly I am redirected to /wp-admin/install.php (welcome screen to install WordPress) as if this is a new installation.

Findings -
I logged into phpMyAdmin from cPanel and found that all tables have old prefix, which means none of the tables are changed to the new one. Makes sense, probably there was a db-rollback due to the db errors.

However, $table_prefix property in wp-config.php file was changed to new prefix. I changed it back to the old prefix and uploaded file to server.

I still get the same behavior though. Access to domain points back to /wp-admin/install.php file.

Anyone has come across this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: (1) renamed plugin directory. didn't work. obviously, as the plugin does one time db name change, and doesn't come into play during runtime. (2) checked code logic. db prefix renaming function returns true (but prefix is NOT changed when viewed from cPanel!). next, it fails to update certain rows in few tables, the error is that <new-prefix>_<tablename> does not exist. So the tables are NOT renamed. (3) wp-config.php file is changed to reflect new prefix.

Comment: Now, Since no apparent changes are done on database (no prefix changes, no row updates) & I changed back wp-config.php to have "wp_" prefix - it should have worked fine. But it doesn't for some reason. I have tried doing 'check table' and 'repair table' on the database, still problem persists. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall plugin or remove change db prefix plugin folder from wp-content/plugins.
2. Change $table_prefix to new prefix.
3. Go to phpmyadmin-> your db-> select each table and rename the table with your new prefix.

For more details refer this link- 
[Change wordpress table prefix](http://codegarage.com/blog/2011/08/how-to-change-your-wordpress-table-prefix/)

Comment: Thanks Pranita. For now I want to reset the changes and get the site back on its feet and running. Without knowing what exactly has happened don't want to mess things further. Would you recommend any steps to reverse changes? Unfortunately I didn't take DB backup :(

Answer (score 0):

1} Remove your plugin ( as you are not able to login in your wordpress admin panel ) then rename that plugin and try to login ... ( you can rename your plugin folder : wp-content\plugins\ -- your plugin -- name

2 } if in phpmyadmin you see your table prefix is changed by new prefix which you enter through plugin , then see which table is seen with old prefix ( just change that with new prefix  : just clicking on resp table >> operation >> rename table name )  or vise-versa

3 } open WP-CONFIG.PHP  and check for $table_prefix=your default or new prefix is what set.

4 } and if you have backup of your database then just replace it with current one and check.

Comment: What appeared is that actually the plugin didnot change any of the table prefixes, and did not update any of rows (where applicable) with new prefix. It only changed wp-config.php to reflect new prefix, which then I changed back to old prefix. So technically everything is the same, still the error (showing wp-admin/install.php page).

Comment: 1} your config.php is mismatched
2} database  prefix is missing or something went wrong 
3} did you try to rename plugin name or delete it from resp folder as i told

Comment: 1) fixed 2) db prefix is unchanged ("wp_") 3) renamed plugin folder name. error persists..

Comment: did you check .htacess file ?

Comment: take a backup of .htacess and delete it and check ? happen. if its exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. To start with I was looking at the wrong DB and thinking that tables were not renamed by the plugin. They were.

Basically 'Change DB Prefix' seems to be a badly written plugin.

Cause -
It was able to rename tables but somehow it appears to have added another '_' to the new prefix. And hence it could not rename the field values in _usermeta table.

Funnily enough the original prefix given for the plugin itself was wrong, in the sense there were no tables with the given 'original' prefix! So the plugin went and created another duplicate bunch of tables.

Basically db automicity was not maintained by this plugin. Makes me wonder how does one miss such basic principle of db mgmt and release a plugin.

Solution -
After analyzing the issue with ever helpful Bluehost tech support, just dropped new tables and modified db_prefix in wp-config.php back to original value. This solved the problem.

Thanks Pranita and user2906577, for your valuable time trying to solve this issue.